# Why is this expression false?

Tags: logic

I have thought thoroughly over this expression $(\:∀x∃y\:(Q(x, y) ⇒ P(x))\:) ≡ (\:∀x\:(∃y\:Q(x, y) ⇒ P(x))\:) $ however I do not understand why they are not equivalent? I thought the "there exists" symbol distributes because P(x) does not use it? Similarly, why is $(\:∀x∃y\:(P(x) ⇒ Q(x,  y))\:) ≡ (\:∀x\:(P(x) ⇒ (∃y\:Q(x, y)))\:) $ true? Because the forall distributes across nonusers?

Sorry about the confusion, the expressions have been updated and finalized.

Comment: Your expressions are still rather ambiguous - can you please parenthesize them to make it clearer precisely how things are supposed to associate?

Comment: If you assume that the first $\forall x$ extends to the first $P(x)$, then one obvious difference is that the RH side of the equivalence involves an unbound variable $x$ (in that the RH $P(x)$ is outside the range of the $\forall x$ on that side), while the LH side does not. If you don't extend the $\forall x$ that far, then the RH side is exactly what the LH side means.

Comment: "there exists does **not** distribute over $\rightarrow$"... Consider the equivalence between $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$; the LHS will be : $∃y(\lnot Q(x,y) \lor P(x))$ and it is true that "there exists distributes over $\lor$", so that the LHS amounts to : $∃y \lnot Q(x,y) \lor P(x)$ (because P(x) does not use it), while the RHS is : $\lnot ∃y Q(x,y) \lor P(x)$. As you can see, the two are different.

Comment: Now, following Ross' answer, consider as $P(x) := (x < 0)$ and as $Q(x,y) := (x=y)$ and check the truth-values of LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $Q(x,y)\to P(x)$ is equivalent to $\neg Q(x,y)\vee P(x)$

So when you distribute the existential over the implication into the antecedent, you have to convert to the dual (that is a universal).

$$\begin{align}\forall x\;\exists y\;\big(Q(x,y)\;\to\; P(x)\big) & \equiv \forall x\; \exists y\;\big(\neg Q(x,y)\;\vee\; P(x)\big) \\[1ex] ~ & \equiv \forall x \;\Big(\big(\exists y\;\neg Q(x,y)\big)\;\vee\; P(x)\Big) \\[1ex] ~ & \equiv \forall x\;\Big(\neg\big(\forall y\; Q(x,y)\big) \;\vee\; P(x)\Big) \\[1ex] ~ & \equiv \forall x\;\Big(\big(\forall y\;Q(x,y)\big)\;\to\; P(x)\Big)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are asking about $\forall x (\exists y Q(x, y) ⇒ P(x)) ≡ \forall x (\exists y Q(x, y)) ⇒ P(x)$.  Note that I have added a set of parentheses to the left side. Now let the domain of $x,y$ be $\Bbb Z, Q(1,1)$ be true and all other $Q(x,y)$ false, $P(x)$ be false for all $x$.  Then the right side is true because the antecedent is false.  The left side is false for $x=1$, so is not true for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For an example showing that $\forall x\exists y(Q(x, y) \Rightarrow P(x))$ is not equivalent to $\forall x ((\exists yQ(x, y)) \Rightarrow P(x))$, take the universe to be $\mathbb{Z}$, $Q(x, y)$ to be $x > y$ and $P(x)$ to be $x > 0$. Then given any $x$, if we take $y = 0$, we have $x > 0$ if $x > y$, which means that $\forall x\exists y(Q(x, y) \Rightarrow P(x))$ is true. However, given $x = -1$ (say), we can take $y = -2$ to get $x > y$, and so conclude that $\exists yQ(x, y)$ is true, but we can't deduce that $x > 0$ from that, so $\forall x ((\exists yQ(x, y)) \Rightarrow P(x))$ is false.

Answer (score -2):

There is a parenthesis after P(x) in RHS. For all distributes over both sides entirely (both over P and Q) for the first expression.